# C array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I have the following piece of code that I don't fully understand :

```
void (*foo[ABC]) (int *i) {
    [A] = function1,
    [B] = function2,
    [C] = function3
}
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are integer constants.

1- Is it a valid declaration if `ABC` has not been defined before?

2- What is this way of initializing called? (`[A] = function1;`)

3- What is the value of `foo[D]`? Is it a null pointer?

Comment: Any useful comments had been buried in all the noise, so I removed them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it won't work if either `ABC` or `A`, `B` or `C` are not defined.
2. The initializers are so called [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) (for C90 a GNU extension and standard since C99, thanks AndreyT)
3. As long as `D < ABC`, `foo[D]` will be 0 (equivalent to a `NULL`-pointer), otherwise it will be undefined.

<s>**EDIT**: as the question is now about what it would mean if <s>`ABC`</s>`Random` and the other indexers are strings the answer is a lot shorter: it won't  mean anything, using strings as array indexes is [undefined behaviour](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).</s>

Comment: Designated initializers is a C language feature since C99, not a GNU extension.

Comment: What does `D < ABC` mean if `D` and `ABC` are strings?

Comment: @Gradient then it wouldn't mean anything since using character-pointers to index arrays is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Gradient: Strings? Where did that come from? If these were strings, you wouldn't be able to use them as in your original post.

Comment: I don't think those are really strings. Seems like OP doesn't know about the existence of the word "identifier".

Comment: Also, "If it has automatic storage (such as within a function), then its value will be undefined." - **no.** Aggregate initialization demands that elements without an corresponding expression in the initializer list are zero-initialized (more precisely: they are "initialized as if they had static storage duration").

Answer (score 2):

"I don't think it's C" is not equivalent with "it is not C".

---

Thanks for [the link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits), @Kninnug -- this is a **horrible** C99 feature (and a GNU extension to C90), and the code has an error: it is a **misspelled** initialization of an array of three function pointers. I could imagine the fixed code like this:

```
#define ABC 3

#define A 0
#define B 1
#define C 2

void function1(int *i)
{
}

void function2(int *i)
{
}

void function3(int *i)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void (*foo[ABC]) (int *i) = {
        [A] = function1,
        [B] = function2,
        [C] = function3
    };

    return 0;
}
```

[This compiles](http://ideone.com/EGpBN8).

Also:

> What is the value of `foo[D]`? Is it a null pointer?

Well, what's `D`? If `D >= ABC` (assuming that they both are non-negative integers), then that element doesn't even exist. If `D < ABC`, then it is a `NULL` pointer, since aggregate (structure, union and array) initialization implicitly zero-initializes elements that have no corresponding initializer expression in the initializer list.

(More precisely, they are initialized "as if they had `static` storage duration", which is initialization to `NULL` in the case of pointers.)

Comment: Now `[ABC]` changed to `[RandomWord]`.

Comment: I change my question to precise that A is NOT a number. It really is the string `A`.

Comment: +1 The [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623884/c-array-of-function-pointers#comment29132787_19623884) one commenting on this _ugly_ syntax !

Comment: @haccks What kind of random word? Clearly that should be a size constant, else it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gradient Let me see that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes that's why I asked: **Then what is `*foo[ABC]`?**, Because it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: In the original code, `Random` is not defined anywhere (in the current file). So I don't know if it is a number or not. For `WordA`, I am sure.

Comment: @Gradient Now your question is a completely different one... It can't really be anything different from a size constant.

Comment: @Gradient: If `Random` is not defined, your code does not compile. That eliminates any reason to discuss it any further.

Comment: @AndreyT If the array indexers are strings the whole thing is undefined behaviour, prepare for [hellspawn from your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: @Kninnug: If the array indexes are strings, the code contains a constraint violation, i.e. it is not compilable. I'm not aware of any compiler that would accept strings as array indices (especially in this context) even as an extension. So, there's no real room for "undefined behavior" here. The code is simply not compilable.

Comment: @AndreyT for string constants yes, but passing a `char *`-variable would have it converted to an integer (without cast, so warned), which would then lead to undefined behaviour. Indeed probably not what the OP meant, but not an impossible situation.

Comment: @Kninnug No, it wouldn't. No womder some compilers claim that it's the case. Not only indexing with a string constant is a constraint violation. Believe what AndreyT wrote, he's right.

Comment: Wow, stupid typo in my testing code. Never mind... Long story short, H2CO3 and AndreyT are right, it's not compilable.